# Binary Conversion with recursive fucntion is giving an odd value

Tags: c++, recursion

I am making a function that converts numbers to bianry with a recursive function, although when I write big values, it is giving me an odd value, for example, when I write 2000 it gives me the result of -1773891888. When I follow the function with the debugger it gives me the correct value of 2000 in binary until the last second. 
Thank you!!

```
#include <iostream>

int Binary(int n);


int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << n << " = " << Binary(n)  << std::endl;

}

int Binary(int n) {
    if (n == 0)return 0;
    if (n == 1)return 1;
    return Binary(n / 2)*10 + n % 2;
}
```

Comment: They are part of a bigger code, this is only a part, but as you wish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integer values in C++ can only store values in a bounded range (usually -2<sup>31</sup> to +2<sup>31</sup> - 1), which maxes out around two billion and change. That means that if you try storing in an integer a binary value with more than ten digits, you’ll overflow this upper limit. On most systems, this causes the value to wrap around, hence the negative outputs.

To fix this, I’d recommend having your function return a `std::string` storing the bits rather than an integer, since logically speaking the number you’re returning really isn’t a base-10 integer that you’d like to do further arithmetic operations on. This will let you generate binary sequences of whatever length you need without risking an integer overflow.

At least your logic is correct!

Comment: Ooh, you're right, I didn't thought about it because 2000 is inside the range, I will change the return type to string. Thank you very much!!